# Spring WS with JAXB2Marshaller - javax.activation.DataHandler NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: jaxb, spring-ws

We are trying to implement a JAXB2Marshaller to our webservice project, but we get a  **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError** on the class **javax.activation.DataHandler**,  however the dependency to **activation** artifact exists and we have verified that the activation.jar is in fact being deployed, so this caused by something else.

Here is the app config:

```
<sws:annotation-driven />

    <sws:dynamic-wsdl id="security" portTypeName="security" locationUri="/">                               
        <sws:xsd location="classpath:security-service.xsd"/>                                                  
    </sws:dynamic-wsdl>

    <bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.GenericMarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter">
        <constructor-arg ref="marshaller" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="classesToBeBound" >
            <list>
                <value>com.app.model.SimpleRoleList</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="schema" value="classpath:types.xsd"/>
    </bean>
```

As always, help is really appreciated.

EDIT--------------

This only happens when the app is deployed to Tomcat 6.

Comment: What happens if you remove that fix?

Comment: @skaffman: Nothing, same error. I'll remove the edit comment so that no one gets confused since its apparently not related.

Comment: You might want to remove the "fix" too, then, it's just a distraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed I had older versions **jaxb-api.jar** and **jaxb-impl.jar** on the Tomcat's endorsed folder than the ones I'm using on the app.
There are two ways of solving this; First one is to remove the jars from the endorsed folder and then add jaxb as a runtime dependency on the projects POM:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

The second one is just to update the jars on the endorsed folder to newer versions (In my case its version 2.2.2).

That fixes it.

Hope its helpful to someone.

Answer (score 2):

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

use this it will support for u